# How to make a Flat UI / Bootsrap dropdown go back up on a mouse event

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to have Flat UI (bootstrap) dropdown go back up on a mouse event.

Simple dropdown:

```
<div class="dropdown" id="mydropdown" >
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown<b class="caret" ></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

js:

```
$("#mydropdown").mouseout(function()
{
    alert($("mydropdown").text());
});
```

See a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/f29dhg84/6/

I put in a mouse handler which captures the event, but cannot figure out what to call to make the dropdown do a dropup. I did an inspect when its dropped down and saw shown.bs.dropdown, but that does not seem to be it.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can toggle the `dropdown` on `mouseout`:

```
$("#mydropdown").mouseout(function()
{
    $(this).dropdown("toggle")
});
```

Updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/f29dhg84/13/